# Should I use LINQ to SQL or XML for my project?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq

My program has 3 text fields, Title, Website, and PictureURL. When I click the 'save' button I want it to add the 3 entries into a log of some sort (LINQ or XML seems like the best choice). Only 1 user will be accessing the program at a time. The log will be local on the machine, and not on an external server. After the 3 fields have been saved as a single entry to the log, I want to be able to load each group of entries from the log back into the textboxes. Would either be a simpler solution or a more appropriate choice for this type of project? I am new to both hence my uncertainty for which would be better.

Comment: Can you clarify if its a multi-user or a single-user application?

Comment: XML doesn't work very well as a database of any interesting size.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote? This will be a single user program. The file it will call to read and write will be local, not located on an external server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With given set of requirements indeed it would be better to stick with XML storage since you have not neither big amount of data nor complex search and grouping conditions nor remote and distributed access. So LINQ-to-XML would suit perfect for such simple desctop application. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Why not LINQ to XML? Assuming local storage is going to be, as you stated, an XML file:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a good answer without knowing more about your situation.

If you are just running this locally on one machine, and do not anticipate the log growing overly large, I'd say XML wold be the better choice, as it requires less setup and overhead than a database.

However, if it needs to scale for size or users, you'll want to use a database. But that will add additional complexity, despite the fact that LINQ to SQL makes it simpler to use.